# How can I use nested loops to print out this triangle word pattern?

Tags: loops

I'm trying to make a pattern that looks like this:
[image]

And am given this code to start:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

class TriangleWord
{
private String word;

public TriangleWord()
{
    word = "";
}

public TriangleWord(String w)
{
    setWord(w);
}

public void setWord(String w)
{
    word = w;
}

public String toString()
{

}
}
```

There's also a runner involved. Please help!!

Comment: This is a programming exercise, so out of scope here.